# How to update a git submodule hierarchy selectively?

Tags: git

I have a repository containing git submodules, such as pthread-win32. When I run `git submodule update --recursive --init` on Linux, all submodules are updated unconditionally; even submodule `pthread-win32` is cloned unnecessarily.

I would like to clone only submodules that are needed for any specific local platform.

Is there a way to tell git which submodules to update recursively based on some condition, such as the name of the local platform?

Comment: How would you do it manually? Script that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `man git submodule`, You can provide the path to a specific sub-module you want to update as an argument:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive path/to/submodule/dir/
```

If the modules are few number you can use the above command multiple times.
Otherwise as a workaround you can put all the selected sub-modules into one directory and use a wildcard as follows-

```
git submodule update --init --recursive mylocalplatform/*
```

Comment: Great, thanks. This works fine for my own repositories, but not in the general case. I guess this would be a new git feature to add.